# Is it okay to use Google Cloud Messaging's Instance ID (now deprecated) for app tracking purposes?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, uniqueidentifier

I am currently using android's device id (ANDROID_ID) as a unique identifier for my own analytics API in my app. I have recently heard that Google under Android 10 (Q), Android will have tighter restrictions in using unique identifiers as stated in https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

> Android 10 (API level 29) adds restrictions for non-resettable identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number. Your app must be a device or profile owner app, have special carrier permissions, or have the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission in order to access these identifiers.

So i went on to use Google Cloud Messaging's Instance ID as a replacement (with GCM dependencies). But then again I saw that the library was deprecated so it got me thinking that the GCM API might be discontinued in the near future.

**Is it still okay to use GCM's Instance ID?** Note that I want to use it only for getting a device's unique ID.

If there are any **suggestions** to another unique ID that I can use, here are my notes:

- Less or no dependencies if possible
- Its okay if the unique ID is refreshed on app uninstall / device factory reset as long as it is globally unique on refresh
- Does not hinder or bother device security
- Easy to setup if possible, if not, must be reusable code
- Minimal (One in a billion chance) or no chance of duplication
- I am aware of Java's UUID, but I am still researching its feasibility

Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT (as of Feb 11, 2020)**

Since generating a unique ID is a very tricky subject, I resorted to using Google's own **Firebase API**. They take care of the unique ID's (provided that your device has Google Play.

To those who want an independent unique ID per device, just stick to the API handling/throwing the unique ID.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since generating a unique ID is a very tricky subject, I resorted to using Google's own Firebase API. They take care of the unique ID's (provided that your device has Google Play.

To those who want an independent unique ID per device, just stick to the API handling/throwing the unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Generating a random 128-bit or longer ID using a cryptographic RNG (such as `java.security.SecureRandom`) is enough for your purposes.

Even for 122-bit IDs (including those found in random UUIDs), the expected chance of a collision is 50% only after generating about 2.7 billion billion values (see "[Birthday problem](https://en.Wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)").

See also "[Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids)", in the Android Developers site, and my section "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)".

Comment: Sure, I'll check it out, thank you. I'll update you as soon as I finish reading your section, for now I want to focus on unique identifiers with almost <1% or no chance of duplication. My app uses a lot of test devices and I am now focusing on android's Firebase and or multi-part self-generated random key.

I will keep the SecureRandom class in mind whether I can integrate it with my random key or not.